# express-stormpath not recognizing environment variables to initialize on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, stormpath, express-stormpath

i have a simple web server, trying to use the npm-package 'express-stormpath' for basic user registration.

everything works fine locally - but consistently getting this error when i deploy to Heroku:

```
 Error: apiKey.id is required.
 2015-10-23T00:23:52.603692+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new RequestExecutor           (/app/node_modules/express-stormpath/node_modules/stormpath/lib/ds/RequestExecutor.js:26:37)
```

i have tried every possible way i can find on the internet to configure this:
1) entirely environment vars, as laid out in https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables

2) a small, private config file in ./stormfront as laid out here : 
['apiKey.id is required' error thrown when using express-stormpath with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251178/apikey-id-is-required-error-thrown-when-using-express-stormpath-with-node-js?newreg=294b3790bdb1478ea46cd4835ba0c083)

3) i've tried the following method, manually creating the apiKey object:

https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath/issues/135

and nothing works on heroku. any tips?

Comment: Here's another SO question you should have a look at [StormPath Node Express Heroku Error 'apiKey.id is required'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983531/stormpath-node-express-heroku-error-apikey-id-is-required).

Comment: funny thing is, if i config as answered there:
 
  client: {
    apiKey: {
      id:  process.env.STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID,
      secret: process.env.STORMPATH_API_KEY_SECRET,
    }
  }

it doesn't even work locally. i have to change 'id' to 'apiKey.id' to get it to work locally...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a momentary bug in our Node SDK, please modify your configuration variables to use these new names:

```
STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID
STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET
STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF
```

We made a new release that accepts these new paramaters, but unfortunately it broke backwards compatibility with the old ones.  We will relase a fix tomorrow, but you can fix the problem now by  using the variables names.  Our apologies for this problem!